# Regex route constraint with negative lookahead

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc-3

Tested with http://regexhero.net/tester/

```
^(?!Bar$)
```

- `Foo` matches
- `Bar` doesn't match
- `FooBar` matches
- `BarBaz` matches
- `FooBarBaz` matches

When setting a route constraint, I have to use `^(?!Bar$).*` to get the same results. Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first expression actually doesn't 'cover' any part of string. See, both `^` and `(?!...)` sub-expressions match at specific positions (anchors) in the tested string (actually they both try to match at the same position - right at the beginning - and fail immediately).

And this - `^(?!Bar$).*` - actually 'covers' all the string. I suppose that's the difference.

Comment: Thank you, I've notified the author of the tester about a possible issue with the tester.

Comment: @Stijn - Raina77ow has a good answer, and I suspect that the Regex Route constraint has code in it behind the scenes to check that the match length equals the string length, which would explain this behavior.  I also answered your question over here... https://getsatisfaction.com/bucketsoft/topics/regex_route_constraint_with_negative_lookahead_in_mvc_3